# ul elements are not positioned at the center in react

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a react project, I have built all the components, but when I run the project it appears that all the ul elements I've used in the components are not in center, they are slightly shifted towards right side of the component.

This is my code for input fields

```
const NumberFactsInputs = ({ state, inputChange }) => {

    if(state.categoryValue === 'trivia' || state.categoryValue === 'math') {
    return(
            <div>
            <ul >
              <li> <input  className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' value={state.number} type='number' placeholder='Number'  onChange={inputChange} /></li>
              <li> <input readOnly className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' value={state.date} type='number' placeholder='MM/DD' style={{opacity: 0.4}} onChange={inputChange} /></li>
              <li> <input readOnly className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' value={state.year} type='number' placeholder='YYYY' style={{opacity: 0.4}} onChange={inputChange} /></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        );
   }
```

this is my main render function which is in container component, where i tried to position everything in the center but the ul elements are not perfectly centered.

```
    render() {
        return(
        <div className='tc bg-light-blue dib br3 pa3 ma3 bw2 shadow-5'>
        <h1>Number Facts</h1>
        <NuberFactsCategories  changeCategory = {this.onChangeCategory} />
        <NumberFactsInputs state={this.state} inputChange={this.onInputChange} />
        <DisplayText text={this.state.displayText}/>
        <ul style={{listStyle: 'none'}}>
        <li style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}> <SubmitButton buttonClick={this.onButtonClick} /> </li>
        <li  className='ml3' style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}> <RandomButton randomClick={this.randomButtonClick} /> </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        );
        }

}
```

The image of the webpage, here you can see, the input fields and buttons are not in center.
[image]

This my css file for the input fields.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

input {
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

There is no css file for ul element which is for buttons, all the styling is done with inline style block.

Comment: I believe, you got css tag missing over here. And, by the way, seeing your relevant CSS would help a lot.

Comment: It would be great if you can create a sample demo.

Comment: I'm guessing the `listStyle` is only removing the bullet points, can you try directly setting a `padding=0` property?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the css file, you can see it now

Comment: @IvanS95 Hey buddy, setting padding=0 of 'ul' worked vey well...Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is the `listStyle=none` is only removing the bullet points from the `ul` element, if you encounter this issue you just need to make sure you remove the `padding` from the list as well.

So just apply `padding: 0` to the `ul` element and you're good to go :)